# Cookie alive after delete on ajax requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have this method which clears my cookies from response and request:

```
    public static void Clear()
    {
        var cookies = HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies;

        cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("notification-status") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2) });
        cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("notification-message") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2) });

        var cookies2 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies;

        cookies2.Add(new HttpCookie("notification-status") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2) });
        cookies2.Add(new HttpCookie("notification-message") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2) });
    }
```

After use this cookies I call this method and on browser inspector the cookies seems to have been deleted, but when I do a request on ajax the cookie appears to be alive, showing the notification twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using Controller TempData (Redirects) and ViewData (For ajax)